# Factory not registered error due to to_s method in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, factory

I created factories for the model ABCD and it's associated models including the model "another_model" which has a belongs_to relation to ABCD.

The model ABCD has a to_s method that returns

```
def to_s
    "Check: #{another_model.check_number} SSNUM: #{something_some_val}"
end
```

Now when I try to test an action in the ABCD_Controller class I get this error.

> Failure/Error: get :document_save, {"abcd"=>attributes_for(FactoryGirl.create(:a_patpay)) }
>
> > ArgumentError:
> >
> > > Factory not registered: Check: 456465 SSNUM: 06122469

Now Check and SSNUM are obviously not attributes of the ABCD Model they are just strings returned by the to_s method in the model. Wondering why FactoryGIrl thinks they are attributes that are not registered...

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, `FactoryGirl.create(:a_patpay)` is defined to return an instance of `ABCD`, which is not a valid argument for `FactoryGirl.attributes_for` and which prints out as you've indicated due to the definition of `to_s`.

Comment: hmmm... does make sense... thanks for your response... how would I rectify it then? I needed the instance of ABCD where I call FactoryGirl.create(:a_patpay)...

Comment: If you just want the attributes for your `ABCD` instance, you can call the `attributes` method on it rather than using FactoryGirl (i.e. `{"abcd" => FactoryGirl.create(:a_patpay).attributes}`. If you don't need to actually create the instance, you can just use `{"abcd" => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:a_patpay)}`. You'll have an `id` key/value pair in the former, but not the latter, but I don't if that makes a difference in this case.

Comment: I think that did it.... it was just a question of appending the "attributes" instead of "attributes_for"... what was I thinking...I kept blaming the poor "to_s" method and did not care to look anywhere else... Thanks for pointing it out...